# How to group, sum, and average times in crossfilter.js

Tags: crossfilter

I am trying to find average time taken by the name. May i know the best way to find total time across all the name as well as the average time taken. Please find the details below

```js
let data = [{"name":"A","children":"8:17:33"},{"name":"B","children":"9:30:45"},{"name":"C","children":"12:45:56"},{"name":"D","children":"4:20:30"},{"name":"E","children":"7:12:38"},{"name":"F","children":"6:29:45"},{"name":"G","children":"11:34:45"},{"name":"H","children":"10:30:45"},{"name":"I","children":"8:34:45"},{"name":"J","children":"8:34:12"}];

let CFX =  crossfilter(data);
let dimName = CFX.dimension( (d)=> d.name);
let grpTime = dimName.group().reduceSum( (d)=> d.children);
console.log( grpTime.all() );
```

```html
<script src="https://square.github.io/crossfilter/crossfilter.v1.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: Here is a custom reduce to do it, but the resulting times come out as strings, and the average values are too large:

```js
let data = [{"name":"A","children":"8:17:33"},{"name":"B","children":"9:30:45"},{"name":"C","children":"12:45:56"},{"name":"D","children":"4:20:30"},{"name":"E","children":"7:12:38"},{"name":"F","children":"6:29:45"},{"name":"G","children":"11:34:45"},{"name":"H","children":"10:30:45"},{"name":"I","children":"8:34:45"},{"name":"J","children":"8:34:12"}];

 let CFX =  crossfilter(data);
 let dimName = CFX.dimension( (d)=> d.name);
 let grpTime = dimName.group().reduceSum( (d)=> d.children);
 //console.log( grpTime.all() );
 let timeGrp = dimName.group().reduce(
  function( p , v) {
   p.count++;
   let time = v.children.split(':');
   p.time += time[0] * 60 * 60 + time[1] * 60 + time[2];
   p.avg = p.time / p.count;
   return p;
  },
  function( p , v) {
   p.count--;
   let time = v.children.split(':');
   p.time -= time[0] * 60 * 60 + time[1] * 60 + time[2];
   p.avg = p.count ? p.time / p.count : 0;
   return p;
  },
  function( ) {
   return {
    time: 0,
    avg: 0,
    count : 0
   }
  }
 );
 console.log(timeGrp.all());
```

```html
<script src="https://square.github.io/crossfilter/crossfilter.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, crossfilter will do sums and averages quite easily, for example you could look at the [annotated source of the stock example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) for many averages. It looks like your times are measured in hours, minutes, and seconds, so it might be easier to convert to seconds before summing.

Comment: @Gordon Let me know where i am missing. Updated in answer

Comment: It's better form to edit your question, so I moved your "answer" into the question. Also, it's crucial to say what's going wrong - I took the liberty of adding that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the trickier things about JavaScript is that it will silently and happily convert strings to numbers, and vice versa, and it doesn't always do this correctly.

In this case, since your times are strings, and splitting those strings produces more strings, you've got a mix of strings and numbers.

But does JavaScript complain? No. It automatically converts strings to numbers, like

```
"8" * 60 = 480
```

But then it also converts numbers to strings, like

```
90 + "9" = 909
```

The right thing to do is convert those times to numbers immediately:

```
let time = v.children.split(':').map(x => +x);
```

```js
let data = [{"name":"A","children":"8:17:33"},{"name":"B","children":"9:30:45"},{"name":"C","children":"12:45:56"},{"name":"D","children":"4:20:30"},{"name":"E","children":"7:12:38"},{"name":"F","children":"6:29:45"},{"name":"G","children":"11:34:45"},{"name":"H","children":"10:30:45"},{"name":"I","children":"8:34:45"},{"name":"J","children":"8:34:12"}];

 let CFX =  crossfilter(data);
 let dimName = CFX.dimension( (d)=> d.name);
 let grpTime = dimName.group().reduceSum( (d)=> d.children);
 //console.log( grpTime.all() );
 let timeGrp = dimName.group().reduce(
  function( p , v) {
   p.count++;
   let time = v.children.split(':').map(x => +x);
   p.time += time[0] * 60 * 60 + time[1] * 60 + time[2];
   p.avg = p.time / p.count;
   return p;
  },
  function( p , v) {
   p.count--;
   let time = v.children.split(':').map(x => +x)
   p.time -= time[0] * 60 * 60 + time[1] * 60 + time[2];
   p.avg = p.count ? p.time / p.count : 0;
   return p;
  },
  function( ) {
   return {
    time: 0,
    avg: 0,
    count : 0
   }
  }
 );
 console.log(timeGrp.all());
```

```html
<script src="https://square.github.io/crossfilter/crossfilter.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more clarification need from you like, Need to find out over all average time (totalAvg/totalCount). Is there any direct way available  using crossfilter grouping logic

Comment: I guess you are looking for [groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll).